# How to remove /magento2/ parameter from URL?

Tags: magento2, php, url, apache, xampp

Current URL :  http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/products/options/types

I want to use without **`/magento2/`**

> i.e. http://localhost/rest/V1/products/options/types

I am using XAMPP server with apache and php.

Comment: what are you using for apache and php? xamp or wamp?

Comment: try `url rewriting`

Comment: Yes I am using apache and php with XAMPP server

Comment: Try to using .htaccess url rewriting or creating a virtual host for that.